# SOAP and XML Encoding

Tags: php, xml, soap, nusoap

I'm wondering if anyone has experienced this sort of problem before.

We've recently installed the native PHP SOAP extension to replace nuSOAP. We are now experiencing a problem in that some XML appears to contain invalid characters, symptomatic of poor encoding.

It's possible that this is completely coincidental and that there is a independent fault with the suppliers system that is generating this XML it would just be a bit of a coincidence!

Could they be related? Would there be a global change to XML settings?!

Many thanks in advance
Rich

Comment: Sorry if I'm stating the obvious but... Are those incoming XML files actually valid? The "appears to" makes me think you haven't really checked... :-?

Answer (score 0):

check your php version. Maybe some functions used in NuSOAP are deprecated.

Comment: Please read the question again. They've actually *dropped* NuSOAP.